# stuck when shutdown or restart ubuntu

Tags: shutdown, reboot

I am very new to Linux. I installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS 5-6 days ago.

When I want to reboot or shutdown the system hangs (I waited more than 3 hours) and then I forcefully shutdown by pressing the shutdown button.

When I press <kbd>esc</kbd> during reboot it shows :

```
wait-for-static stop/waiting
stopping rsync daemon rsync [ok]
speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
asking all remaining processes to terminate... [ok]
killing all remaining processes... [fail]
ModemManager[654]: could not aquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager' service name
Modemmanager[654] ModemManager is shutdown
deactivating swap... [ok]
mount: / is busy
will now restart
```

When I press <kbd>esc</kbd> during shutdown it shows :

```
wait-for-static stop/waiting
stopping rsync daemon rsync [ok]
speech-dispatcher disabled: edit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher
asking all remaining processes to terminate... [ok]
ModemManager[654]: Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quantity updated(20)
killing all remaining processes... [fail]

ModemManager[654]: could not aquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager' service name
Modemmanager[654]: Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: state changed (registered -> disabling)
Modemmanager[654]: Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: signal quality updated (0)
Modemmanager[654]: Modem /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: access technology changed (gprs -> unknown)
Modemmanager[654]: Caught signal, shutting down...
deactivating swap... [ok]
mount: / is busy
will now halt
```

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I also have this. *(but I didn't press <kbd>Esc</kbd> though)*. When it hangs I press the power button on the machine, it shuts down after about 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Well I recommend you to edit your grub file as follows:

Open terminal and become root by issuing

```
sudo -i
```

Edit grub file.

```
nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line starting **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT** and edit that like as follows :

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
```

Now update grub by issuing

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot your system.

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I Find the line starting GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and it is same as u recommend me .
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios" , however i reboot by using "sudo reboot" the problem is still same , it hangs on reboot or shutdwn.

Comment: i use grub customizer , go to "general settings" in it go to "kernel parameters" and set "quiet splash reboot" to "quiet splash reboo=pci" or  ="bios" but nothing change . problem is still same.