# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS stuck at restart

Tags: 20.04, freeze, reboot

I know that [this problem is already asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/815918/stuck-when-shutdown-or-restart-ubuntu) but for very old versions of Ubuntu. I have tried the solution with most number of votes. It fixes the freezing issue at shutdown but still freezes when I reboot.

Here is the content of my `GRUB`.

```sh
(base) hell@Dell-Precision-T1600:~$ cat /etc/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=force"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

My GPU is Nvidia Quadro 2000 and I use GNOME desktop environment (Legacy MBR boot partition) if that is relevant information.

Comment: Installing my 18.04 System in Legacy Bios Mode was the only fix I could figure out when I had this problem...

Comment: Yes this one is also in legacy mode, but its 20.04 not 18.04.